# how to do i get returned data from ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am getting a undefined on the username from $sql which should be the returned data from the query.

```
$('#userlist').on('change', function () {
var selected = $("select option:selected").text();
console.log(selected);
// use ajax to run the check
$.ajax({
    url: '/php/connect/userdropdowncheck.php',
    type: 'JSON',
    data: selected,
    success: formfill,
    error: function (xhr, status, err) { console.log(xhr, status, err); }
});

function formfill(sql) {
    var username = sql['UserLogin'];
    var email = sql['UserEmail'];
    var admin = sql['admin'];
    var firstname = sql['firstname'];
    var lastname = sql['lastname'];
    var title = sql['title'];
    var company = sql['company'];

    console.log(username);

    if (username.length > 0) {
        console.log('Found user');
        console.log(username);
        $('#username').html($username);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Failed to find user');
    }
}

});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'anonconnect.php';

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername= $_POST['selected'];  

$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserLogin= :login");
$sql->execute(array(':login' => $myusername));
$user = $sql->fetch();

/*** close the database connection ***/
$dbh = null;

if($user->rowCount() == 1){
    echo 1;
     echo json_decode($user);
else {
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

It is pulling the text from the selected drop down just fine and passing it but the function on the return cannot find it.

Comment: What's a console.log($sql) show you?

Comment: console.log 1 = tanahara

console.log 2 = undefined

console.log 3 = <br />

console.log 4 = <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in     <b>/home/wushuass/public_html/pbx/php/connect/userdropdowncheck.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: you have a syntax error in your if statement, please follow my answer

Comment: I added the json_decode($sql); still getting the same errors.

Comment: I think the problem is on how i am getting the variable sent from jquery to php. Is the $myusername = $_POST['selected']; correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your jquery code could be:

```
function formfill(sql) {
    var username = sql['UserLogin'];
    var email = sql['UserEmail'];
    var admin = sql['admin'];
    var firstname = sql['firstname'];
    var lastname = sql['lastname'];
    var title = sql['title'];
    var company = sql['company'];

    console.log(username);

    if (username.length > 0) {
        console.log('Found user');
        console.log(username);
        $('#username').html($username);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Failed to find user');
    }
}

$('#userlist').on('change', function () {
var selected = $("select option:selected").text();
$.ajax({
    url: '/php/connect/userdropdowncheck.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {UserLogin:selected},
    success: function(data){
        formfill(data)
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) { console.log(xhr, status, err); }
});

});
```

and your php code:

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'anonconnect.php';

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername= $_POST['UserLogin'];  

$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserLogin= :login");
$sql->execute(array(':login' => $myusername));
$user = $sql->fetch();

/*** close the database connection ***/
$dbh = null;

if($sql->rowCount() == 1){
    //echo 1; //if you echo this it will cause that your jquery code will not be able to read the response as JSON and serialize it in array
     echo json_encode($user); // php array to json object
} else {
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: I am getting this now.

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in <b>/home/wushuass/public_html/pbx/php/connect/userdropdowncheck.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />

Comment: ok you fixed one issue but there is still another different issue, your query returning 0 rows, check your query

Comment: Im sending the variable selected to the php code so i use $_post['selected'] to get it correct ?

Comment: but you are defining the var `$sql` as a array `$sql = $sql->fetch();` and then recalling it as an object `$sql->rowCount()`, my suggest is to use another var name `$user = $sql->fetch();` and change `return $sql;` as well to be `return $user;`

Comment: I changed it still same problem I think its coming from the way im trying to get the data sent from the js file.

Comment: actually you have a lot of issues in your code, let me fix it for you i'll edit my answer

Comment: Still getting a problem with username being undefined. the table column is correctly named. I use this select code elsewhere in the website.

Comment: can you add `console.log(selected);` after `var selected = $("select option:selected").text();` and check if it's getting the proper value please

Comment: I already did and yes it is getting the text perfect each time. The dropdown it is getting the text from is populated by a select statement looking at the UserLogin column of the Users table. is json_decode what we want to use after changing the type to post in the ajax?

Comment: NO, after changing to `POST` there in no need to decode it since it's not `JSON` anymore, but can you check the results of php page after receiving `POST` request from your ajax code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36066/discussion-between-user1552172-and-maverick)

Answer (score 0):

If you using **JSON** type, you can serialize your javascript array and then pass to php.

Ex: `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(Array);`

In php, use `json_decode()` and `json_encode()`

Ex: `$data = json_encode($sql)`

Comment: @user1552172 , @MaveRick : I think you have to echo using json_encode() **NOT** json_decode()
`echo json_encode($user);`

Comment: In js, use `JSON.parse(JsonString)` It will return js array